# Universal Framework Binaries: Why Build Simulator and Archive Device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a [script provided by Greg Brown](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-universal-framework-in-xcode-9) to successfully build a universal framework binary. Here are the two lines that invoke xcodebuild:

> xcodebuild archive -project $FRAMEWORK_DIR/$FRAMEWORK.xcodeproj -scheme $FRAMEWORK -sdk iphoneos SYMROOT=$BUILD
>
> xcodebuild build -project $FRAMEWORK_DIR/$FRAMEWORK.xcodeproj -target $FRAMEWORK -sdk iphonesimulator SYMROOT=$BUILD

Note that the **archive** action is being used to produce the device (arm64 architecture) whereas the **build** action is being used to produce the simulator (x86_64 architecture).

---

In a different article entitled [iOS 9 Universal Cocoa Touch Frameworks](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/ios-9-universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks/) the author remarks: "Note that you will both have to **build** with your Simulator and **Archive** with your device to get a universal."

---

So, what's up with **build** vs **archive**? Why not build both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, what's up with build vs archive? Why not build both?

The way it works is that Apple doesn't allow simulator binaries (x86_64 and i386) to be uploaded to the app store. If your frameworks contain those binaries, then you won't be able to upload the containing app to the app store.

You would distribute your framework with all the possible binaries so that it can run on Simulators and devices alike. But would like to strip off those Simulator binaries before uploading to the app store.

P.S. I've explained this in detail in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394079/distributing-ios-framework-as-file-or-pods/46250651#46250651). The answer also explains as to why the issue doesn't exist when using frameworks via Cocoapods.

Edit:

The difference between build vs archive is that archive accepts a scheme to run.

```
An Xcode scheme defines a collection of targets to build, a configuration to use when building, and a collection of tests to execute.
```

Also,

```
You cannot use archive option for the iOS Simulator platform.
```

You could essentially use xcodebuild build for both of the platforms. You will essentially get the same result. The commands that I use to build my framework are as follows (both commands use the build action):

```
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but I don't think that you answered the question. You point out that we cannot submit universal binaries to the app store. Okay, correct. But my question is about the procedure used to purposefully create a universal binary

Comment: My apologies. I misread the question. I've updated the answer with more information.